# NuxtImg resizing images not working on different screens

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm using nuxt 2 and nuxt-img to display the website images.

To improve the website performance i'm trying to use sizes attributes from nuxt-img.

here is an example :

```
<nuxt-img
  src="/logos/nuxt.png"
  sizes="sm:100px md:400px lg:300px"
  />
```

What i expected from this was that on 'sm' screens display a 100px image, 'md' 400px and 'lg' 300px.

what i'm getting is on 'sm' a 300px img , 'md' a 400px img and on 'lg' again a 400px img.

any ideas what could i be doing wrong?